# Why get a DeadlineExceededException in MakePersistentAll from app engine data store?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

Folks -- I am getting the following exception and can't explain why. The number of objects to persist are usually small (<10), but I get a DeadlineExceededException intermittently when using makepersistentall from the persistencemanager.

The http request code also handles other queries into the datastore prior to the makepersistentall call. Looking at the exception trace, it looks like there is some stuff related waiting for an object.

What is the issue and how can I solve this exception? Thanks

====

The pertinent code is

```
  // handle the updates
  List<InterestQueueItem> interested = getInterestedUsers(locx, locy, gamecode);  // this also results in a query into the datastore, which looks like it goes well
  List <BingoUpdate> topersisteUpdates = new ArrayList<BingoUpdate>();
     try {
   for (InterestQueueItem item: interested) {
    if (!item.getUID().equals(this.uid)) {   // no need to update the originator of the update
     BingoUpdate update = new BingoUpdate(item, screenname+" not working");
     update.setContent("some content");
     topersisteUpdates.add(update);
    }
   }
   pm.makePersistentAll(topersisteUpdates); // exception thrown here
     } finally {
      pm.close();
     }
```

BingoUpdate constructor does not do much -- just getters and setters.

GetInterestedUsers is

```
public static List<InterestQueueItem> getInterestedUsers(float locx, float locy, String gamecode) {
List<InterestQueueItem> retVal = new ArrayList<InterestQueueItem>();
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
Query query = pm.newQuery(InterestQueueItem.class);
    try {
        // reduce the potential set of interested folks
        query.setFilter("gamecode == thisGameCode");
        query.declareParameters("String thisGameCode");                 
        retVal.addAll((List <InterestQueueItem>) query.execute(gamecode));
        return retVal;
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
}
```

Exception is below:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (61c89aa7e7f35f42) started at 2010/10/26 03:56:13.421 UTC and was still executing at 2010/10/26 03:56:42.750 UTC.
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
 at com.google.apphosting.runtime.AsyncFuture.get(AsyncFuture.java:54)
 at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.get(ApiProxyImpl.java:412)
 at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.get(ApiProxyImpl.java:244)
 at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:42)
 at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper$CumulativeAggregateFuture.get(FutureHelper.java:136)
 at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:71)
 at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:32)
 at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$2.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:115)
 at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$2.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:112)
 at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionRunner.runInTransaction(TransactionRunner.java:31)
 at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.put(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:112)
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.RuntimeExceptionWrappingDatastoreService.put(RuntimeExceptionWrappingDatastoreService.java:117)
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.put(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:182)
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.put(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:127)
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjects(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:254)
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.BatchPutManager.processBatchState(BatchPutManager.java:35)
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.BatchManager.finish(BatchManager.java:54)
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager$BatchManagerWrapper.call(DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager.java:127)
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager$BatchManagerWrapper.access$200(DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager.java:121)
 at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager.makePersistentAll(DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager.java:98)
 at com.goodconcierge.UpdateQueueThread.run(UpdateQueueThread.java:112)
 at com.goodconcierge.BingoServerServlet.handleLeave(BingoServerServlet.java:92)
 at com.goodconcierge.BingoServerServlet.doGet(BingoServerServlet.java:24)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:693)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:97)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
 at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:238)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
 at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
 at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
 at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:261)
 at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:8486)
 at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:8484)
 at com.google.net.rpc.impl.BlockingApplicationHandler.handleRequest(BlockingApplicationHandler.java:24)
 at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:418)
 at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$RpcTask.runInContext(Server.java:572)
 at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:448)
 at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:688)
 at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:326)
 at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:318)
 at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:446)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Comment: what does the BingoUpdate constructor do? what does the getInterestedUsers method do?

Comment: Edited post above. Essentially BingoUpdate constructor does nothing special. getInterestedUsers is doing another query into the datastore

Comment: my guess is that getInterestedUsers is chewing up your wall clock time.

Comment: The doc about the exception : http://code.google.com/intl/fr/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Request_Timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You whole HTTP request takes more than 30s and got killed.

Despite the exception points to "persist all" call, it may be not the root cause. Could be, for instance, that getInterestedUsers takes 29s, and persist() simply have no time to complete. You should place tracing around the code lines measuring how long they take.

If it will be found that the root cause is indeed persist(), make sure you do not have cascade persistence above necessary. You may have only a few top-level objects, but if they have one-to-many links, you may load and then persist thousands objects, and be unaware of it.

Try to run the code on local machine, monitoring actual SQL statements (I don't remember if AppEngine allows it? it should).